# Nested subscriptions in Angular with iteration on first result

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Since this morning I'm trying to solve a really headache-giving issue.

I'll begin by explaining the (really simple) situation.

I've created Groups, which are composed of a title, and an array of members, only given by their id string.

Now, I want to display these Groups. Simple isn't it ? 
However, I don't want of course to just display the ids of the members, but the complete informations on users of the groups (such as basically their names...).

So, I have of course a service for getting all Groups, and another for getting a User by its Id.

In React, since I'm not using rxjs, I wouldn't have any problem ; async/awaits and Promise.all would do the trick.

However here, several problems appear while trying to get complete infos (calling the 2 services) before rendering it, as:
1. I want to get the groups
2. iterate on it
3. iterate on group members
4. finally for each member get its id. Therefore each group could have a groupcompleteusers array for example, that i would fill each time I would be getting the info on the users from the id...

So I tried the following: 
- first I tried to play with async/awaits, Promises, but since I'm calling services returning Observables, I'm a bit lost. 
- then I tried to have nested subscriptions. However, I'm completely unable to write it properly, as I'm not only iterating on groups, but also on group.members (which is not existing at the time of the nested subscription, as group is at that time an Observable...)

So, with angular 7/rxjs 6, I tried the following :

```
getGroups(){
this.groupsService.getGroups().pipe(
  flatMap(group => 
    {
      for(let member of group.members){
        this.userService.getUser(member);
      }
    }
    )
).subscribe(u => this.groups = u)


}
```

Of course, it's not working, especially as group.members doesn't exist at that time...

So I'm a bit stuck.

Maybe some have a clue?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the data that comes back from `getGroups()` look like? You can use `.toPromise()` on an `Observable` to convert it into a promise if that's easier?

Comment: Someting like this:
`
0: {members: Array(2), _id: "5bf08b2740262431d4a42066", name: "Développeurs", __v: 0}
1: {members: Array(1), _id: "5bf132e31416a71984f7a600", name: "test", __v: 0}
2: {members: Array(1), _id: "5bf13339a09ee20a705de359", name: "test2", __v: 0}
3: {members: Array(1), _id: "5bf1339ca09ee20a705de35a", name: "test3", __v: 0}
`
with an array of members containing only the string ids.

I'd tried .toPromise() but didn't really understand it....

Comment: Note that no matter how you solve this in the frontend, it still requires a *lot* of network requests, making it slow and unscalable. Rethinking the API would be something to consider here.

Comment: Interesting to use Promise though here, really simpler in my mind, however still have that problem where i can't to do a map on what is considered as an object...

Comment: @IngoBürk I'm sharing your point of view, however I'm just wondering on the fact that on the other hand it's not a solution as well to save complete users in groups, for integrity reasons (modifying an user would imply to modify also that user in groups...)

Comment: How you store the data is one thing, how your API puts them together another thing. Unless you use something like Firebase, then the problem gets trickier in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

The `flatMap` function expects you to return an `Observable`, so you can do something like:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

getGroups(){
  this.groupsService.getGroups().pipe(
    flatMap((groups: any[]) => {
      let members = groups.map(grp => grp.members)
                          .reduce((res, arr) => res.concat(arr), []);
                          .map(member => this.userService.getUser(member))
      return forkJoin(members);
    })
  )
).subscribe(u => this.groups = u)
```

Here, we use `map` on the array to convert it from an array of `members` to an array of `Observable`. We then use `forkJoin` to join the array of `Observable` into a single `Observable`, and return that to `flatMap`

Comment: Nice man thanks! But however, it's always stucked by the fact that I can't call .members on group, as group is considered as an Object, hence do not have the property "members"...

Comment: Do you have a model class for `Group`?

Comment: Yep, that's : const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    members:Array
})

Comment: I've updated the answer so it should compile, but if you have a class definition you can use that instead of `any`. Alternately, in the definition for `getGroups`, I am assuming it's an HTTP call? If so, change it from `http.get()` to `http.get<any>()`, and it will change the type from `Object` to `any`

Comment: Hang on, is `groups` an array?

Comment: Well I think so, at least the result of subscribing simply to this.groupService.getGroups() is an array...

Comment: Try that, I've not had a chance to try and compile the code, but that should work...

Comment: Getting undefined where?

Comment: Well in fact with your solution, the code is not even trying to reach the API (no GET request is really sent to the back). the getUser service is though contacted, as I noticed with console.log, but, if I modify my http request with non sense, I don't even get a 404 error...

Comment: Ive just made an edit to add the `forkJoin` function, which I had missed out. Try that

Comment: Oh yeah, of course... Sorry, I should have noticed it.

Well it begins to work, apart from the fact that "u" is just giving a list of the members, not the array of groups with attribute for each group with this table, but maybe now I can try to fix it...